# Problem with the error * A server error occurred. Please contact the administrator * django rest framework

Tags: django-rest-framework, backend, django-urls, django-settings

I am trying to test some basic backed fonctionnalities but I seem to have this error **A server error occurred.  Please contact the administrator** while trying to connect to the localhost http://127.0.0.1:8000 or http://127.0.0.1:8000/sise/.

At first I had this error showing **django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf 'Dashboard_sise.urls' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.** but After I commented this line in the settings file **ROOT_URLCONF = 'Dashboard_sise.urls'** the error changed into **A server error occurred.  Please contact the administrator**.

Can anyone please help me figure this problem out, I already tried changing the urlpatterns in the urls.py files but it didn't work, I also tried manipulating the MIDDLEWARE section in the settings file but nothing changed.

This is the Dashboard_sise.urls code

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.sites.urls),
    path('sise/', include('Dashboard.urls')),
]
```

This is the Dashboard.urls code

```
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter
from Dashboard.views import *

router = DefaultRouter()

router.register(r'accee', AcceeViewSet, basename='accee')
router.register(r'rapport', RapportViewSet, basename='rapport')
router.register(r'prise_fonction', PointageUtilisateurViewSet, basename='prise_fonction')

urlPatterns = router.urls
```

and finally the settings file

```
# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '+f-@$j*(-8^*7ijk@6_hpki@)am4e%na6ttp)54@-ddcs0#fgy'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
PREPEND_WWW = False

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'corsheaders',
    'Dashboard',
    'frontend'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
]


TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]
        ,
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'Dashboard_sise.wsgi.application'

'''ROOT_URLCONF = 'Dashboard_sise.urls'''


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'MainCourante',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'root',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

APPEND_SLASH = False


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'


'''REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
        'rest_framework.authentification.BasicAuthentification'
        'rest_framework.authentification.SessionAuthentification'
        # 'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthentificated'
        # 'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny'
    )
}'''

        
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True  # If this is used then `CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST` will not have any effect
```

Thank you in adavance

Comment: The first error is probably the main problem, it says that there might be circular imports. Perhaps you can include the complete code in the urls file.

Comment: I edited the code, for now I am trying to test only these 03 urls in the Dashboard.urls code

Answer (score 1):

I will answer this in case someone faced the same bug. I had a problem with the database structure .. The models implemented in the models.py file and the database created didn't match so it kept showing me this error ... once I fixed the models.py file it all worked well

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this was the cause.

```
urlPatterns = router.urls
```

its usually `urlpatterns`.

Comment: I changed it in both urls files but the error is still showing

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort to help me, I fugured it out ...  the problem was in the database structure , it wasn't related to the url.py as the error showed